# List view updates view which are not touched

Tags: android, xml, listview

Sorry for the bad title.

I am adding a toggle button at run-time to the list view.
When I click on the button its state gets changed. But the problem is that when I scroll down other items get selected too.

For example, if click on first toggle button the 6th toggle button gets checked too.

This is a very weird behavior.

Here is the XML code for the acitivty

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/eros_now_title_bar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_button_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_imageview_width_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_imageview_width_height"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/back_image_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_imagebutton_width_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_imagebutton_width_height"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/npd_back_feedback" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back_button_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_button"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
                android:text="Invite friends"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_bar"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_blue_white"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/friends_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_above="@+id/invite_count_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:divider="@color/transparent">

        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/invite_count_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/eros_now_title_bar"
                android:text="10 more invites to go"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />


            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the XML code for the view I am inflating in the adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/person_pic"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:riv_corner_radius="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey600_36dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Grumpy brother"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <!--<ToggleButton-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginRight="35dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
        <!--android:background="@drawable/invite_selector"-->
        <!--android:textOn=""-->
        <!--android:textOff=""-->
        <!--android:text="" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the code for getView

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

Log.e("getView", "name = " + contacts.get(i).getName());

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.friend_view, parent, false);
}
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    RoundedImageView image = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_pic);

    ToggleButton selector = new ToggleButton(activity);
    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        selector.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp));
    else
        selector.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, getPx(35), 0);
    selector.setLayoutParams(params);
    selector.setTextOff("");
    selector.setText("");
    selector.setTextOn("");
    selector.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    selector.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
    selector.setChecked(contacts.get(i).getSelectedState());
    contacts.get(i).setButton(selector);
    RelativeLayout card = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    card.addView(selector);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), contacts.get(i).getURI());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        contacts.get(i).setURI(Uri.parse(""));
    }

    name.setText(contacts.get(i).getName());
    if (!contacts.get(i).getURI().toString().equals(""))
        image.setImageURI(contacts.get(i).getURI());
    else
        image.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_person));

return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you used **contacts.get(i).getSelectedState()** to set ToggleButton state in **getview**.

Did you use **Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()** to update the listview's state?

If not, add that code after toggle the button.

Answer (score 0):

Because your item view is reused so only create ToggleButton if convertView is null. If convertView is not null, get it from convertView and set it's properties.

Use setTag and findViewWithTag to identity your ToggleButton.